# How to show more than one view controller scene in one page of storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new in IOS programming. I learn xcode and swift by designcode. 
In the article, I see that they can put more then one view controller scene in one page in storyboard. Like this one.

[image]

but in my xcode just like that.

[image]

Comment: please select one viewcontroller from design and try to move around you can find all.

Comment: I guess that your scenes are overlapping, try to move them around by dragging from their header.

Comment: Thank you all. I solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

My scenes are overlapping. Just need to move them by dragging from their header. Thanks to @Alladinian .   Thank you to help me!